# Not loading results non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the results of a MySQL table with the column name 'teachername' what's happening is, when I search the the name I am getting a error which states I am trying to get the property of a non-object.

Here is the code..

```
if (isset($_GET['teacher'])) {

 $teachername = $_GET['teacher'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM assignmenthandout WHERE teachername = $teachername";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
      echo $row["assignmentname"]."<br />";
    }
  } else {
    echo "There are no assignments due";
  }
```

The line the error is reffering to is

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Thank you!

Comment: I sincerely doubt that the teacher's name is an integer. Then again, some treat us as numbers *huh?* ;-)

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at Prepared statements `SELECT * FROM assignmenthandout WHERE teachername = $teachername` screams SQL injection to me.  http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: enclose $teachername in single quotes like this '$teachername'

Comment: @Maantje by prepared statements, what do you mean?

Comment: @MoniXx Thank you, that fixed it!

Comment: @miotk Here is a post about it http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: @miotk by prepared he means this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Maantje haha beat me to it.

Comment: @Maantje can that be done with a SELECT? the same, other than using the select?